# chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener not working as it should

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get  `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` working , but my app button just does not click, and no console output.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "version":"1.0",

    "name":"STFU",
    "description":"Mutes Tabs Which are not required ;)",

    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon":"icon.png"
    },
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
console.log("Hello World");

function yo(){
    console.log("yo");
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(yo);
```

After extensive googling, I did remove my popup from the manifest and also declared my script in the background of manifest, but still to no avail. How should I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you looking for the console output?

Comment: I was trying to press F12>Console

Comment: Then you're simply looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Um, better dupe candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension (can't fix it easily now)